# Discrete Math Function - Unsure about Symbol

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, notation

Working through a chapter about functions, and I'm a bit unsure how to read the below:
[image: function]

For example, for the f(1), is this outputting the absolute value of (1+1/3)?

Comment: It’s the [ceiling function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function $\lceil \cdot \rceil$ is the *ceiling function* or the *least integer function*.  This function takes a real number $x$ as an input, then gives the least integer greater than or equal to $x$ as output.  For example:

$$ \lceil 1 \rceil = 1, \qquad
\lceil \pi \rceil = 4, \qquad
\lceil -\tfrac{3}{2} \rceil = -1, \qquad\text{and}\qquad 
\lceil 1.00000000001\rceil = 2.$$

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! I'm glad I asked.